# Python - Split a list with a long string based on 2 keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-itertools

I have a list with a long string in it. How can I split the string to extract the sections from 'MyKeyword' to 'My Data'. These words appear multiple times in my list so I'd like to split it based on this and include the MyKeyword and MyData if possible

Current data example:

```
['MyKeyword This is my data MyData. MyKeyword and chunk of text here. Random text. MyData is this etc etc ']
```

Desired output:

```
['MyKeyword This is my data', 'MyData.', 'MyKeyword and chunk of text here. Random text.','MyData is this etc etc ']
```

Current code:

```
from itertools import groupby
#linelist = ["a", "b", "", "c", "d", "e", "", "a"]
split_at = "MyKeyword"
[list(g) for k, g in groupby(output2, lambda x: x != split_at) if k]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression, matching all the text from `MyKeyword` to `MyData` in lazy mode:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("MyKeyword.*?MyData\.?","MyKeyword This is my data, MyData. MyKeyword and chunk of text here. Random text. MyData is this etc etc ")
['MyKeyword This is my data, MyData.', 'MyKeyword and chunk of text here. Random text. MyData']
```

- `.*?` means 0 to infinite characters, but in lazy mode (`*?`), i.e. as less as possible;
- `\.?` means an optional period.

---

**EDIT** (according to the new requirement):

The regex you need is something like

```
MyKeyword.*?(?= ?MyData|$)|MyData.*?(?= ?MyKeyword|$)
```

It starts from the point where it matches `MyKeyword` (resp. `MyData`), and then it catches as less characters as possible, as above, until it reaches `MyData` (resp. `MyKeyword`) or the end of the string.

Indeed:

- `|` is a special character which means "or"
- `$` matches the end of the string
- `?` is an optional space
- `(?=<expr>)` is called positive lookahead and it means "followed by `<expr>`"

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to not include the second word (MyData) - so it only extracts up till just before MyData, then runs again with My Data to MyKeyword?

Comment: @qwerty12 I'm not sure I have understood, please edit your question clarifying your expected output or open a new question.

Comment: apologies, have updated the desired output so it makes more sense

Comment: Try with the following regex: `MyKeyword.*?(?= ?MyData|$)|MyData.*?(?= ?MyKeyword|$)`. If it is what you want I'll update my answer with an explanation ;-)